# Can you identify attributes of a shapefile on the gps?

Tags: trimble

My company uses Trimble GeoExplorer 6000 GPS units and pathfinder office software. Is there a way once a shapefile is created to bring up the attribute table on the gps unit? We have been loading previously recorded data to the gps as a background file. When I return to a site this allows me to see where the data was collected but I can't see any information to identify the attributes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will want to use the import utility, select your shapefile  and then select properties within the import utility.  Under the data tab you'll want to choose the correct option.  It sounds like you want the second option, Data Dictionary File Only, because you have already created a data dictionary.  If you're using Terrasync (which it sounds like you are) you are going to want to Update Features and not Collect Features.  Update Features is what allows your to see the attributes of the data already collected